# Permanently disable wlan0 on raspberrypi running ubuntu 20

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, raspberrypi

Ubuntu 20 seems to manage networking devices differently. All instructions on disabling wlan0 are tailored to Ubuntu 19 and earlier. I tried blacklisting 'wlan0' in modprobe.d, didn't work.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  Ubuntu 19?   I'd assume you're talking about Ubuntu Core 20, however there was no Ubuntu Core 19.  Some clarification on what releases you are talking about may help (Ubuntu server & desktop releases use the *yy.mm* format, yes specialist *snap* based releases do use *yy* but only come out on even years)

Comment: 20.04 for Raspberry Pi 64-bit https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Answer (score 6):

Following the same principle and dogma (everything changes, "panta rhei") as in the previous comment, please do the following on a raspberry pi 4, having Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Add these two lines in the file **/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt** and never edit the "**config.txt**".

```
dtoverlay=disable-wifi
dtoverlay=disable-bt
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out! 
Edit /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt.
add in

```
dtoverlay=disable-wifi
```

.save and reboot

Answer (score 0):

Everything changes, "panta rhei" an so on, and so on... Nowadays, using Raspberry Pi 3B and Ubuntu Server 20.10, the proper file is: `/boot/firmware/config.txt`.  I added there:

```
dtoverlay=disable-wifi  
dtoverlay=disable-bt
```

Because, BT is also unwanted for my servers' purposes. Reboot and wifi disappeared. Hope BT too.
Beware: file: `/boot/firmware/config.txt` isn't empty, so editing it try to not have zeroed its content.
Thanks for leading toward the right way.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is looking for this, I haven't found an answer anywhere so hopefully it will help someone else.

For `Ubuntu Core 20`, the `config.txt` is found at `/run/mnt/ubuntu-seed/config.txt`. Add your config there. The active file is found at `/var/lib/snapd/seed/config.txt`, which is a `read-only` copy of the latter overwritten at boot.